# Multi template files for a content type

Tags: theming

is it possible to use multiple templates select for a content type. I am thinking of having a select_list which will be shown while adding the content and you can choose how your page will look like, based on existing template files.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You can use [hook_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) to do this, eg, something along the lines of:

```
function YOURTHEME_OR_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  $node=$variables['node'];

  $foo= /* get the value of this field from $node */ ;

  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $foo;

  // or....

  switch ($foo) {

    case 'FIRSTVALUE':
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__FIRSTSOMEOTHERSTRING';
      break;

    case 'SECONDVALUE':
      // etc etc etc

  }

}
```

and then Drupal 7 will look for a `node--WHATEVER.tpl.php`.

ADDITION:

If you are wanting the PAGE itself to be different based upon this field, then you would use [hook_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) with similar logic but using `page__WHATEVER` instead in the theme hook suggestions and `page--WHATEVER.tpl.php` in the template names.

Answer (score 0):

You could, in theory, use the page.tpl to check for content type and change the HTML accordingly,  however,  it would be far easier to actually create content types.   they exist for the exact purpose you're describing,  and the CMS admin functions are already there to handle doing that for it.

Comment: `It would be far easier to actually create content types` ?  Could you expound upon or clarify this?